# Storyboard: Can't add textField to cell in UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

Am having trouble dragging a textField to a cell in a UITableViewController. It just won't stick. Why is this?

Here are my settings:

Content: Static cells
Style:Grouped
2 rows to a section

Am trying to insert textField into one of the cells, but won't stay in place.

Comment: did you solve it? having the same issue, too.

Comment: Yes, my label was too big for the field. When I made it smaller, it worked. Sorry for the delay in responding; hope it works for you.